# Mobile Safari Scrolling Issue - Over scrolling and rubber banding

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

https://youtu.be/6sPKC7XgFq4

The video shows my issue. On any other device, this site scrolls from left to right, but not up and down, and will stop scrolling at the end of the content. As you can see, on mobile safari, the whole page is free floating and rubber bands beyond the edge of the border area. The header also floats around a bit.

I attempted playing with the overscroll-behavior tag, but couldn't get it to fix the problem. Googling at this issue comes up with a ton of similar but non-applicable issues, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Any ideas?

Now I'm considering getting an old beat up iPhone 6 or 7 to test these things.

my HTML - https://pastebin.com/2Y6L5qXm
my CSS - https://pastebin.com/0KKTKW6b

```html
        <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Enright Design Foundry | Hand-Hammered Graphics Web and Video</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
     // http://www.dte.web.id/2013/02/event-mouse-wheel.html
    (function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
    })();
      
     $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
     </script>
    <!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
    <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
    <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/dr-sugiyama:n4:default;carter-one:n4:default;hammersmith-one:n4:default;knewave:n4:default;codystar:n4,n3:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <header>
      <div class="headwork">
       <a>DESIGN</a>
       <a>LAYOUT</a>
       <a>WEB</a>
       <a>VIDEO</a>
      </div>
      <div class="headcontact">
       <a>CONTACT</a>
      </div>
     </header>
     <div class="fswrap">
      <div class="hero">
        <a class="border" href="#pg2">
           <img class="divborderhero" src="images/edge_do.svg" alt="edge border"/>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="topl">
       <a class="border">
           <img class="divborder" src="images/edge_do.svg" alt="edge border"/>
       </a>
       <a class="grow" href="/design.html"><h1>Design</h1></a>
       <a href="www.google.com"><h1>Layout</h1></a>
       <a href="www.google.com"><h1>Web</h1></a>
       <a href="www.google.com"><h1>Video</h1></a>
      </div>
      <div class="topmt">
            <img src="images/bezcurvelogo.png" alt="Bezier Curve Logo"/> </div>
        <div class="topmb">
       <h1>Hand Hammered Design</h1>
        </div>
          <div class="topr" id="pg2">
           <img class="divborder" src="images/edge_o.svg" alt="edge border"/>
        </div>
         <div class="bottoml"></div>
          <div class="bottomr">
        <img class="bioarrow" src="images/arrows.svg" alt="arrow"/>
        <a class="about">
         
         I am a creative professional and public affairs expert with six years of honorable naval service. Let me help you take your brand to the next level.
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

This page should scroll horizontally but not vertically, and stop when it reaches the end of the content. Total page is 1vh x 2vw.

Comment: So in safari the issue is happening? and not in other browsers like chrome, firefox etc.,

Comment: Correct. Desktop safari, chrome, mobile chrome and firefox all scroll properly.

Comment: I just got an iPhone 6s to test, as I've never owned an ios device. It seems this is an issue with 100 vh and 100 vw on mobile safari. I'm still searching around to find the solution.

I've got the same issue with this much simpler site using css grid.
https://pastebin.com/ykpiw9xm

Comment: For anyone who may find this in the future, I never actually solved the issue directly, and it seems mobile safari has a weird issue about 100 vw or vh. just created a media query for ios only using @supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) and changed everything to percentages.

I'm convinced there's a simple solution to this issue, but I've not found it. This is what happens when we tell all graphic designers they have to be web devs in order to eat.